# Profinite group with $2$-generated closed prosoluble subgroups

Tags: group-theory, solvable-groups, profinite-groups

I'm working in a problem and in the order to solve it, I'm stuck on a claim.

> Suppose that each $2$-generated closed subgroup of a profinite group $G$ is prosoluble. Is it true that $G$ is prosoluble?

I cannot find a counterexample.

Given a $2$-generated closed subgroup of $G$, we can write
$$\overline{\langle x,y \rangle} = \varprojlim \pi_i(\overline{\langle x,y \rangle}) = \varprojlim \overline{\pi_i(\langle x,y \rangle)}$$
where $\pi_i: G \to G_i$ are the projections. Writting
$$G = \varprojlim G_i$$
we have that $\overline{\pi_i(\langle x,y \rangle)}$ is a soluble subgroup of $G_i$. My knowledge in soluble groups is not very large, so... is there a way to use it in order to show that $G_i$ is soluble?

**UPDATE.** I found a result from Thompson saying that *a finite group $G$ is soluble if and only if every $2$-generated subgroup is soluble.*

So, if $\langle x_i,y_i \rangle$ is a $2$-generated subgroup of $G_i$, then there is a correspondent $\overline{\langle x,y \rangle}$ $2$-generated closed subgroup of $G$ such that $\pi_i(\overline{\langle x,y \rangle}) = \langle x_i,y_i \rangle$. So, $\langle x_i, y_i \rangle$ is soluble, which implies $G_i$ soluble.

Comment: Just to clarify: you have solved positively your own question. You might paste the update as an answer and accept your own answer.

Comment: @YCor ok! I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a $2$-generated closed subgroup of $G$, we can write
$$\overline{\langle x,y \rangle} = \varprojlim \pi_i(\overline{\langle x,y \rangle}) = \varprojlim \overline{\pi_i(\langle x,y \rangle)}$$
where $\pi_i: G \to G_i$ are the projections. Writting
$$G = \varprojlim G_i$$
we have that $\overline{\pi_i(\langle x,y \rangle)}$ is a soluble subgroup of $G_i$.

There is a result from Thompson saying that *a finite group $G$ is soluble if and only if every $2$-generated subgroup is soluble.*

So, if $\langle x_i,y_i \rangle$ is a $2$-generated subgroup of $G_i$, then there is a correspondent $\overline{\langle x,y \rangle}$ $2$-generated closed subgroup of $G$ such that $\pi_i(\overline{\langle x,y \rangle}) = \langle x_i,y_i \rangle$. So, $\langle x_i, y_i \rangle$ is soluble, which implies $G_i$ soluble.